# Spaces and adjacent letters

Tags: c

i have 2 exercises that i need to do i did most but i am stuck now .
for the first one i need the pc to detect spaces and if there is to type incorrect input but idk how can i let the pc detect them .
for the second i need it to type if there are two letters adjacent in the alphabet
example 8#a8d?g.#@ i need it to type ad . another example 7mK#e*gb!c type (eg) plus if they are already types in the first line then type No such two letters
like b?a0a the first line b?a0a should be the answer and second line if there are 2 letters adjacent (they have same answer)so type No such two letters.
the second question should order the alphabet and if there already is 2 letters in order then type them .
first Qs:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, decimal;
    printf("Enter 5 bits");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    b = a / 10000;
    c = a % 10000 / 1000;
    d = a % 1000 / 100;
    e = a % 100 / 10;
    f = a % 10;
    if (b <= 1) 
        if (c <= 1)
            if (d <= 1)
                if (e <= 1)
                    if (f <= 1)
    {
                        f = f*1;
                        e = e*2;
                        d = d*4;
                        c = c*8;
                        b = b*16;
                        decimal = b + c + d + e + f;
                        printf(" your decimal value is %d",decimal);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("incorrect output");
    }


    getch();
```

2) second Question :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    char string[100];
    int length;
    int i;
    char largest = 96; // Init to a value not in ASCII table
    char smallest = 121; // Init to a value not in ASCII table
    printf("enter string number ");
    scanf("%d", &length);
    printf("enter the string ");
    scanf("%s", string);
    //length = strlen(string);


    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z') {
            if (string[i] < smallest) {
                smallest = string[i];
            }
            if (string[i] > largest) {
                largest = string[i];
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = smallest; i <= largest; i++) {
        printf("%c", i);
    }
    printf("\n");

    getch();
}
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Too broad. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: One question per post, please! And does your program work? Do you get the expected output? Any warnings/errors?

Comment: @CoolGuy Sorry i will keep that in mind next time . and ya they work just  fine but i need to add extra functions but idk how.

Comment: `if (b <= 1) 
        if (c <= 1)
            if (d <= 1)
                if (e <= 1)
                    if (f <= 1)` → `if (b <= 1 && c <= 1 && d <= 1 && e <= 1 && f <= 1)`

Comment: Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve] pay special attention to the parts on readability and formatting.